# "Interceptar" SMS entrante desde app Android Studio , Android 6.0

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql

Quisiera saber como puedo interceptar un sms en Android 6.0 desde mi app, tya que es un servicio tracker y recibe el link de maps desde un sms que previamente hemos mandado "Where" al tracker y el responde, me interesa que al darle al botón mande el mensaje, que YA LO TENEMOS y intercepte el sms entrante. 
Gracias, recuerdo que es 6.0 y si podéis ponedlo detallado, gracias!